# What if partition type and file system type don't match?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems

For example, If I set the type of one partition to 0CH (FAT32(LBA)) and format it to NTFS, can operating system read that partition correctly, will it cause data loss? why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, having tried this in VMware, I can now say with confidence that it does absolutely nothing. I created a partition, formatted it with NTFS, all using Windows 8.1. Then I booted Linux, changed the partition type to 0xb (W95 FAT32, according to `fdisk`) and rebooted to Windows. Aaaand nothing happened. The drive letter was still assigned and everything in order.

Generally, all modern operating systems rely on magic bytes at the beginning of a partition to identify the filesystem. [Here](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~tschwarz/coen252_07Fall/Lectures/NTFS.html)’s some extensive information on NTFS, including the description of what’s contained in a partitions boot sector.

Comment: Modern operating systems may ignore those numbers, but back those were assigned, they were probably meaningful.